# How to prevent empty files being created

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Can someone let me know to prevent the target file being created whenever the source is empty file in informatica power center.

Comment: Test that data exists before saving.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. The way PowerCenter works is it tries to make sure Soures and Targets are available yet before processing any data. So as part of the session initialization, it tries to open connections to Sources and Targets. In case of target flat files an empty file is being created to confirm destination is available and appropriate access rights have been granted.

Only after these steps PowerCenter starts to process the data. There is a bunch of results / sideeffects:

1. If there is no data at source, an empty file will be left on target location
2. If file names are created dynamically, the initially created file with random name will be left empty in target location

The only remedy is to have a command that removes the empty files as part of the Post-session success command.